# angular 2 type script compiler unable to find components and html file after placing it inside subdirectory

Tags: angular

I m trying my hands on angular 2 with type script . I m referring to [5 MIN QUICKSTART](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) and  every thing was working fine .But when i tried to separate my components into separate folder , type script compiler is not able to find the component in those folder. I m kind of stuck here can anyone help. I m not adding any code since I don't know what and where the problem is.

```
 ng-2
 |
 |-app
 |   |
 |    - main.ts
 |   |
 |    - app.component
 |   |
 |    -layouts
 |          |
 |          -  header.component.js
 |          -  header.component.html
 |          -  header.component.css
 |          
  -index.html
  -package.json
  -tsconfig.json
  -typings.json
  -systemjs.config.js
  -node_modules
  -typings
```

this is my project structure.
every thing was working when header.component was in same level with app.component.ts but when i placed it inside layout folder it start giving error.

```
localhost/:16 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/layouts/header.component.ts.js
```

I did adjusted imports like wise, but no difference...

Comment: Please share your code and error

Comment: the code is same as in the link . the only thing i changed is i put my new component in new folder inside app directory. i can update project structure if you want.

Comment: Try like this - import { NewComponent } from './app/new.component';

Comment: no difference @sanket

Comment: Look for folder layout / layouts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was copy-paste issue. I just dragged header.component.ts to `Layouts` folder so the respectice js file was left behind in app folder. When i created new header.component.ts inside layouts folder it worked. My bad sorry!!!

Comment: I guess cats help to get rid of copy-pest ;-)